# how can i refresh current permissions In Bigquery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, permissions, refresh

after get some permissions from Admin, How can I refresh my current permissions? I clicked the f5 button but refreshed did not change,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0cUi.png)

how could I refresh the current permissions?

Comment: Not sure to have understood what you changed and where you want to see your permission evolved. I can also recommend you to ask Antoine Castex internally at L'Oréal.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.